# delete operation on instance itself versus on constructor that created it

Tags: javascript

I'm a little confused as to how the `delete` keyword works in JavaScript.

I have a `Parent` and a `Person` constructor. I've instantiated `person1` and set its `name` property with `person1.name = "newPerson"`. If I run the following code:

```
delete Person.name
```

it deletes the property. However, `person1.name` still exists and `console.log(person1.name)` returns `"newPerson"`. Conversely, if I

```
delete person1.name
```

the `name` property from the `Parent` object is instead called and acted upon.

In the first case, `delete` doesn't remove the property from the given instance but from the `Person` constructor. In the second case, `delete` removes the property from the `Person` constructor and all instances created from it. I know `delete` doesn't affect variables in JavaScript, e.g., `person1`; how does `delete` function in this case, though?

```
function Person(){
    this.name = "person";
}
function Parent(){
    this.name = "parent";
}
Person.prototype = new Parent();

var person1 = new Person();
person1.name = "newPerson";

delete (Person.name);
console.log(person1.name);
```

Comment: `Person.name` is not the same as `Person.prototype.name`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  What do you want to delete?

Comment: just trying to see how delete key affects function constructors and instances created from it

Comment: @Barmar can you explain your answer a little.it was not clear enough to me??

Comment: You seem to be expecting `delete (Person.name)` to delete the name property from the prototype for the `Person` function. But `Person.name` doesn't have anything to do with the prototype, it's refers to a property of the `Person` function itself.

Comment: so you are suggesting if i have two instances of Person say,person1 and person2.Then delete person1.name will delete name property from preson1 but person2 still have this property.But if i add name property using Person.prototype.name then deleting Person.prototype.name will remove name property from both the instances!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing `delete (Person.name);` you are trying to delete the [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) property of the function `Person` which does exist(which is a non configurable property). It has nothing to do with the `name` property on its instance.
if you do `console.log(delete (Person.name));` you will see [false in non-strict mode](http://jsfiddle.net/0mr42n7c/1/) and it [will throw an error in strict mode](http://jsfiddle.net/0mr42n7c/). And the sole purpose of [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) is to delete a property from an object. And yes function can have properties  example:-

```
function Person(){
   this.name='person'; //Available on the instance of Person or on any of the prototype chain it belongs to
}

Person.refName = "something"; //This is not on the instance of the Person
```

and you can delete:-

```
delete (Person.refName)
```

> delete is only effective on an object's properties. It has no effect on variable or function names.

If you want to delete the property from the object just remove from its instance, ex:- `delete person1.name`.

Answer (score 2):

The `delete` operator in javascript is primarily for removing a property from an object.  You do NOT delete objects in javascript.  Because it's a garbage collected language, the way you free an object is to remove all references to it (e.g. all variables that have a pointer to it).  When you've removed all references to it, the garbage collector will free the object.

You can clear a reference to any object by setting it to `null` (or any other value) or waiting until the variable goes out of scope.

In your specific example:

```
delete Person.name
```

does not do anything because `Person` is a function object and that function object doesn't have a property named `name`.  The property `name` it looks like you are asking about is on the instance of a `Person` object that is stored in your `person1` variable.  So, you could so

```
delete person1.name
```

if you really wanted to delete the property from that particular object.

---

Also, your comments about deleting things from the `prototype` do not make sense to me.  Nothing is deleted from a prototype in either of your code cases.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with his question. He's not trying to delete the instance, he's just confused about the relationship between the `name` property in the instance and the prototype chain.

Comment: @Barmar - the first part was background - I've filled in more specific content and I'm working on writing more.  It isn't clear what the OP is actually trying to do some I'm trying to explain the `delete` operator in general and how it applies to the objects the OP has.

Comment: Person.hasOwnProperty(name) returned false but person1.hasOwnProperty(name) returned true.why there is no name property on Person constructor?? if there is no name property on Person constructor then what this.name='person' statement even mean??thanks.i am quite new to object oriented JS concept.i am trying to clear some confusing terms :)

Comment: @user3138436 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Comment: @user3138436 - `this.name='person'` is adding a property named `name` to whatever object `this` points to (in your case, that object is a newly created object made from the `Parent` or `Person` constructor.  It operates no differently than if I did `window.whatever = 1`.  That adds a property to the `window` object.  Adding a property in this way has nothing specific to do with a constructor - it's just a Javascript capability.

Comment: @user3138436 - Calling a constructor as in `var person1=new Person();` creates a new object that inherits from the `Person.prototype` and then calls the `Person` constructor, passing that new object in the `this` pointer.  This allows the constructor to finish configuring that new object before it has finished being created and is returned from the `new` operator.  You seem to be a bit confused about what a constructor actually is.